# Do I need to escape data passed to wp_localize_script()?

Tags: wp-localize-script, escaping

Title pretty much says it all. I took a look at the source, and I didn't see any escaping being done. But, I can't say for sure.

```
wp_localize_script( 'script-hook', 'object_name', array(
    'param_1'   => $value_1, // This?
    'param_2'   => esc_js( $value_2 ) // Or, this?
) );
```

Comment: What happens when you try running text that needs to be escaped through it?

Comment: What? Experiment myself when I can just ask the internet? :) I'm not an expert on XSS, but when I passed in a string with a script tag, this is what was output: `var object_name = {"param_1":"<script>alert(\"xss\");<\/script>"};` no alert was triggered on initial page load. Is that conclusive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know `wp_localize_script` doesn't escape data any more than is necessary to produce valid JSON, and everything is sent as a string. The function was originally designed to allow translating the strings used in your JS into other languages (hence the "localize" part of the function name). So if the data you're passing is coming from a user input or is otherwise user-generated then you'll definitely want to escape it.

Comment: This. It escapes to make valid JavaScript. Nothing more. If you need to escape for some other use, do so.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Perhaps a note should be made in the code reference or Codex?